# How to test for MU via functions.php?

Tags: theme-development, multisite

What is the call to determine, from a theme's functions.php whether the site is an MU site or not?

Updated with answer:

```
$dir = 
 is_multisite() ? 'wp-content/blogs.dir/'.$current_site->blog_id.'/files/' 
 : 'wp-content/uploads/';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the `is_multisite()` conditional, more documentation here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_multisite

You may find the `is_main_site()` conditional useful as well. Just note that `is_main_site()` will always be true if `is_multisite()` is false.